# can Rpi 4 model b work as keyboard emulator to two pc?

Tags: usb, pi-4, keyboard, otg

I am using Raspberry pi model B. I Connected one keyboard to it in usb2 port and I want to write in two pc whatever i am typing on keyboard. right now i tried for one pc. connected keyboard and OTG c pin port to pc. but my question, can i config one of usb ports so it can display on another pc what i type on keyboard simultaneously on both pc?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not clear. A USB port certainly cannot display anything, and I doubt you can type simultaneously on two keyboards.

Comment: no no. sorry if not understood. its my bad. i want to type in single keyboard and want to display on two pc. in keyboard emulation example, otg port i am connecting to pc that i want to see on another pc also. single keyboard(single input) and two output like 2 otg. but in rpi4 only one otg is there. so i have to use one usb if possible. so usb can be used in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate low speed USB (1.x) over GPIO.  You might need some circuitry for 5V 3.3V interfacing but it is doable.  Here is an example of someone patching such a system into an esp https://github.com/cnlohr/espusb